# Why is the converter not used in this JPA query?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have an entity in which I am using a custom type for an attribute:

```
@Entity
public class Person {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private Username username;
}
```

There is a converter for Username which translates it from String and back:

```
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class UsernameConverter implements AttributeConverter<Username, String> {
...
}
```

In my JPA repository there are some methods that query by Username. Simple ones work but others, such as those that put the value in a database function call, don't:

```
public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, Long> {
    // This one works
    @Query("select p from Person p where p.username=:username")
    Person getPersonByUsername(@Param("username") Username username);

    // This one doesn't
    @Query("select p from person p where UPPER(p.username)=UPPER(:username)")
    List<Person> findPeopleWithUsernamesLike(@Param("username") Username username);
}
```

The first method works, but the second one results in an exception:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not determine a type for class: org.myorg.myapp.people.type.Username
```

Why does this fail? Is there documentation on the circumstances under which the parameters will be converted? I'm aware that with @Id-annotated attributes and native queries, parameter conversion is not performed. This doesn't seem to be either of those.

Comment: I think the reason is the letter case. In the second method, the entity class name should be `Person`.

Answer (score 0):

The converter you are defining is a JPA feature, therefore processing it happens on the JPA side of things.

Spring Data JPA doesn't know about these converters and therefore doesn't apply them. 
The SpEL expression in your second query gets interpreted by Spring before anything gets passed to the JPA implementation.

In order to make it work you can register an instance of the converter in the `EvaluationContext` of the SpEL expressions or make the conversion method available in the `Person` object itself and call it in the SpEL.
You can find more details how to do that in this [blog article introducing SpEL expressions for annotated queries](https://spring.io/blog/2014/07/15/spel-support-in-spring-data-jpa-query-definitions).